# How to turn off automatic deletion of unused imports in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

VS Code automatically deletes unused imports and even more annoyingly it deletes imports that are used, but commented out. So for example, if I was to save this code:

```
from pprint import pprint
# pprint("foo")
```

It would remove the first line. So how can I turn this feature off, because it constantly forces me to rewrite the imports?

Comment: Please list what Extension you have enabled in vscode. It is likely a setting in one of those is causing this.

Comment: So I have Pylance, Python Environment Manager and Prettier. Also things like Jupyter, Doxygen and CMake. which I honestly don't remember installing.
Prettier would seem like the offender here, but I disabled it and VS Code was still removing imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `settings.json` ([**User** and **Workspace**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohhel.png)) for the following settings, delete this configuration or change it to `false`.

```json
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true,
    },
```

Comment: I was having an issue with pylance rewriting relative imports (.foo) into incorrect full imports (repo.bar.foo). Setting fixAll to false fixed this.
It also fixed pylance removing unused imports (however I didn't encounter an issue with it removing commented out imports).

Answer (score 1):

Search for "editor.codeActionsOnSave" in settings. click "Edit in settings.json"

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": "never"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your settings.json

```
      "source.ignoreInitModuleImports": "always"
```